# How to get ref to a selected link text

Tags: lexicaljs

I have lexical editor, and I want to get reference of a link currently selected/clicked (so that I can position a layover on top of it for the purpose of editing the link) using react?

For example, "link" in the below text.

This is a lexicaljs text with a [link](https://lexical.dev/) that I want to get ref of...

Answer (score 0):

If your links are custom `DecoratorNode`s then you can handle the events in the output React component. I've done this and it works well.

If you're using the default `LinkNode` then you can try `NodeEventPlugin` from `@lexical/react/LexicalNodeEventPlugin`. It lets you attach event listeners to specific node types. You could add a "click" event and access the DOM node from the event object. I'm afraid this is only theoretical since I've only read about it, but the code should look something like this:

```js
<NodeEventPlugin
  eventListener={(e) => {
    const linkElement = e.currentTarget;
    // Open editor UI
  }}
  eventType="click"
  nodeType={LinkNode}
/>
```

I'm not sure if the event listener approach would also work for selection. If it doesn't, you can try using `useLexicalNodeSelection(nodeKey)` to detect selection state and then accessing the element directly with `editor.getElementByKey(nodeKey)`.

The [Lexical Playground](https://playground.lexical.dev/) has a version of what you're looking. Try poking around the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/tree/main/packages/lexical-playground) to see how they've done it.